# what is the name of this type of encode?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

If you copy and paste the following text in a html page,

```
&#1575;&#1606;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;
```

you will the following Arabic text:

> انوان

My question is:

What is the name of this type of encoding that include numbers and hash (#) sign, and how decode it in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are... HTML entities (or "Numeric character references" for the nitpickers).

Try [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Example:

```
$foo = html_entity_decode('&#1575;&#1606;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;');
// gives you the arabic words in $foo
```

(If the string is in the form `&amp;#1575;...` you need to apply `html_entity_decode` twice. (I don't know if codaddict's edit is valid.))

Comment: Those are not entities. Only *amp* is an entity but `&amp;` is an entity reference (it references the entity *amp*). The rest are just (numeric) character references.

Answer (score 3):

These characters are known as [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML). Basically, they're a safer way of representing characters such as `&` and other symbols that might have meanings in HTML. All characters have a corresponding HTML entity.

You can decode them in PHP by using [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert_uudecode() function for decode.

```
<?php
echo convert_uudecode("+22!L;W9E(%!(4\"$`\n`"); //It prints I love PHP!
echo "\n";
echo convert_uudecode('&#1575;&#1606;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;'); //It prints WU±
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use proper terminology:

- `&amp;` is an **entity reference** that references the entity named *amp*.
- `&#1575;` is a **character reference** that references the character U+0627 (1575 in decimal) in the Unicode character set.

Both references are [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3) as they only reference single characters. But entities can also represent more than just a single character.